# car suddenly stop on hill/ circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

[image: Textbook question]

For car a it's simple, kinetic friction= mass*9.8*1.0
kinetic friction =mass*9.8
a=kinetic friction/mass=9.8m/s^2

but for car 2 is what i would like to ask about:
the centripetal acceleration is v^2/r, which is 25^2/200 which is 3.125m/s^2 in direction of the centre of the circle, while the acceleration from friction is 9.8 m/s^2

but the answer of the question says its 12.9m/s^2, which is the sum of the acceleration from friction and centripetal acceleration. so how can that be when they're perpendicular to each other?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for the acceleration due to the kinetic friction is incorrect. Remember,
$$
f_k = \mu_kn,
$$
where $n$ is the normal force. To find the normal force, you have to use what you know about the centripetal acceleration. Draw a free-body diagram, and label the weight of the car and the normal force, and then you know that
$$\vec{n}-\vec{w}=m\vec{a}_r,
$$
where $a_r$ is the radial, or centripetal, acceleration. Since you know $a_r$ and you know the weight of the car, you can find $n$. Then plug that in for the $n$ in the expression for the kinetic friction, and then you can solve for the tangential acceleration. Since, in general,
$$
n\neq mg,
$$
your tangential acceleration won't always be 9.8 m/s$^2$.

Comment: Just started typing an answer like this when you dropped this one in.  Nothing to add.    A good point to remember is that the normal force is **not** necessarily equal in magnitude to the weight, and it is **not** a Newton's 3rd law reaction to weight.